# Characterization of projective modules in terms of Ext groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-modules

This is from Hartshrone exercise 6.6 part (a).

Let $A$ be a regular local ring and $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module, prove the following

> $M$ is projective $\iff$ $\operatorname{Ext}^{i}(M,A)=\{0\}$ for all $i>0$

The hint is to use the following

**Proposition (6.11 A)**
If $A$ is a regular local ring, then

(1) for every $M$, pd$(M)\le \dim(A)$  where pd(M) is the projective dimension and dim(A) is the Krull dimension

(2) If $K=A/m$ then $\operatorname{pd}(K)=\dim(A)$

and to use the descending induction to prove that $\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,N)=\{0\}$ for all $i>0$ and all finitely generated $A$-module $N$. Then finally show that $M$ is a direct summand of a free module.

I really don't know how to put together all this information. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Isn't there somewhere a book with the exercises of Hartshorne solved? This manual is famous enough to have that thing as an attachment.

Comment: I don't know actually

Comment: What's the point of making a trivial editing? You have two good answers, aren't you satisfied with them?

Comment: Yes of course, just to be more precise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along the lines of Hartshorne:

by (1) for all finitely generated $\mathrm{N}$ we have $\mathrm{Ext^i(M,N)}=0$  ($i>\mathrm{dim(A)}$).

Since $\mathrm{N}$ is finitely generated, we may find an exact sequence of the form
$$0\rightarrow\mathrm{K}\rightarrow\mathrm{A}^{\oplus r}\rightarrow\mathrm{N}\rightarrow 0.$$
Taking the $\mathrm{Ext^i(M,-)}$ long exact sequence and using the vanishing $\mathrm{Ext^i(M,A)}=0$ shows that $\mathrm{Ext^{i+1}(M,-)}=0$  implies $\mathrm{Ext^{i}(M,-)}=0$, as required by descending induction.

For the last claim consider an exact sequence of the above form for $\mathrm{M}$ instead of $\mathrm{N}$; the condition $\mathrm{Ext^{1}(M,K)}=0$ means that it must be split.

Answer (score 6):

If $M$ is projective, then $\mathrm{Ext}^i(M,-) = 0$ for every $i>0$; this is because $\mathrm{Ext}$ can be computed by taking a projective resolution of the first argument.

For the converse, we prove a more general result: Let $R$ be a noetherian local ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module with finite projective dimension. (The first hint guarantees this.) Suppose that $M$ is not projective. Then $\mathrm{pd}(M) > 0$, so a minimal projective resolution of $M$ looks like
$$
0 \to F_p \to F_{p-1} \to \cdots \to F_0 \to 0
$$
(Here $p  = \mathrm{pd}(M)$ and $p>0$.) Since this is a minimal resolution, the entries in the matrix describing the map $F_p \to F_{p-1}$ is inside the maximal ideal. Hence
$\mathrm{Ext}^p(M,R)$ is the cokernel of the dual of this map, which is nonzero, by Nakayama lemma. (The entries in the (dual) map are in the maximal ideal, so it cannot be surjective.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your very beatiful answer. I accept the SWS answer just because is more appropriate to my question (he has solved the exercise using the hint from Hartshorne).